# PHP Upload to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am attempting to store files in a MySql database based upon [this article](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx). Before you suggest I store files on the file system and not in the database the files uploaded will be stored and relate to records in the database. I could keep a path to the files and just the file names but I want users to be able to modify and delete the files directly through the web interface. So, let's just pretend that storing in the database is a good option and not discuss others.

My issue is when I go to download the file the data returned from the BLOB in the MySql database is not exactly what I uploaded in test. If I use the function of *addslashes* then binary wise it is completely off. If I remove that function from the routine then I get much closer.

Using a Binary Diff application I can see that, while not using *addslashes* the file data returned has one additional byte of data at the beginning of the file and in turn one less byte at the end. The remainder of the file's data is offset by one due to this little feature of the download.

I am using a FORM to submit the data and enctype is set to *multipart/form-data* as it should be. Here's some code I'm using to get it all to work. **DAL** in the code references a class I created for my Data Access Layer. It handles all saving and retrieving routines and doesn't seem to be injecting any new data. I've checked by looking at the file's content before it goes to my DAL class for saving and the extra byte is already there.

**upload**

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $_FILES['userfile']['content'] = fread($fp, $_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    $_FILES['userfile']['content'] = addslashes($_FILES['userfile']['content']);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = addslashes($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    }

    $fileDAL = new DAL("files");
    $newID = $fileDAL->SaveItem($_FILES['userfile'], false);

    echo "<br>File ".$_FILES['userfile']['name']." uploaded as ID $newID<br>";
}
```

**download**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $objFiles = new DAL('files');
    $objFile = $objFiles->GetItem($id);

    header("Content-length: $objFile->size");
    header("Content-type: $objFile->type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$objFile->name");
    echo $objFile->content;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You do realise you can use `unlink()` to remove files from the hard drive as well? You don't need store the files in the DB just to get around that.

Comment: Is your file larger than 16MB? If so you will need to chunk it into the DB to get around the size restriction.

Comment: addslashes() is total garbage and should have been ripped out of PHP, violently, long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I add an extra line feed or carriage return at the end of a PHP file that was in my headers prior to this code being executed. It caused the header upon writing to include the line feed (OA) in the binary data for file saving.

Answer (score 0):

use **mysql_real_escape_string()**.
excerpt from its man page:

> Escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a mysql_query(). **If binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used**.

so I would change the escaping part of your code to:

```
if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
    $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = stripslashes( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );
}
$_FILES['userfile']['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. Sounds reasonable. Thanks for the info.